# How to use powershell to Import CSV file into Access 2010 Database

Tags: ms-access, powershell, csv

I am looking for a code example or logical flow for taking a CSV file and importing it into an MS Access DB.

I have some powershell scripts which use the export-csv and I am currently importing these into access manually. My goal is to fully automate the process in access.

I have powershell code to create the tables ahead of time, so that is not an issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer you are looking for:

http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-windows-powershell/155962-using-import-csv-post-entries-access-db.html

There isn't much I can add to what is already explained by a couple of excellent Powershell pros.

Here is the relevant post:

> you can use ADO to connect to access :
>
> see for an example :
>   http://mow001.blogspot.com/2006/02/s...h-answers.html
>
> you can use the out-datatable from here to convert the CSV to a dataset :
>
> http://mow001.blogspot.com/2006/05/p...pdate-and.html
>
> then you can use a dataadapter to write back the datatable :
>   here is an helperfunction I mostly use for this :
>
> function get-DataAdapter ($SelectCMD){
>   $da = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLDataAdapter($SelectCMD)
>   $scb = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder($da)
>   $da.UpdateCommand = $scb.GetUpdateCommand()
>   $da.InsertCommand = $scb.GetInsertCommand()
>   $da.DeleteCommand = $scb.GetDeleteCommand()
>   $da
>   }
>
> now you can write back by using this command :
>
> $da.update($Table)

You will have to adapt the helper function to use oledb instead of the SQLDataAdapter since you are talking to Access but that should be the easy part.  These guys did the legwork for you.